# how to check if my graphql server is down

Tags: reactjs, graphql, frontend, apollo-client

How to check if my Graphql server is down. Currently I make a query on the server using QueryResult and if I get an error I record it. I want to make sure that graphql is up and running before making a query. Is there any way of checking the same in react js. Thank you.

Comment: What do you need it for? If you want to make sure your servers are up you should use some specialized monitoring software instead of making requests (so you can get alerts, response times, etc.)

Comment: I want to integrate it in my application rather than looking up a monitoring software. I want my front end application to throw an error message to the customer if it is not able to connect to the server rather than attempting a query and then throwing an error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field to your Query type for that purpose like `status`, `ping`, etc.

```
type Query {
  status: String!
}
```

And then query your server like normal to determine if the server is available:

```
query {
  status
}
```

The request will simply fail if the server is down and you can display whatever messaging accordingly. You can expand on this approach and send down additional information as well. For example, if your server is up but in maintenance, you can return a message to that effect.

Comment: I am already recording the error after hitting the query. I wanted to know if there is a way to catch the errors before querying the graphql server. For example, if the server is down I do not want to hit it by making a query.

Comment: @Tanu Either expose a query field, or a separate endpoint your client can hit. There's not some magic solution here that's not going to involve an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no solution to know if the grapphql server is down without hitting a query. We should though not the server with multiple queries, but make the first query and according to the response we get we should hit our other queries in the application. We can use network and graphql error to handle error scenarios.